# ¿que servidores se usan con las aplicaciones móviles?

Tags: servidor

quiero hacer una aplicación móvil con React Native,postgreSql y php destinada a android no creo que sea necesario aclarar pero por las dudas es una aplicación híbrida,pero no tengo idea de de que tipo de servidor usar,o que tipos de servidores hay para las aplicaciones moviles,creo que estoy confundido,en desarrollo web uno puede optar por wamp o xamp,entre otros más pero en las aplicaciones moviles como es el tema?investigue un poco y me encontre con apache cordova como servidor de aplicacion moviles,pero intenté buscar alguno más pero nada,alguien que me oriente como es por favor el tema de servidores con las aplicaciones moviles,gracias por su tiempo

Comment: Me parece que estás confundiendo conceptos: para una aplicación móvil web/híbrida no necesitas un servidor; es una aplicación auto-contenida que se ejecuta en el navegador del móvil y no necesita servidor (aunque puedes comunicarte con un servidor usando servicios). Cordova/Ionic/Electron/etc son frameworks que facilitarán el desarrollo móvil con tecnologías web, pero no son servidores.

Answer (score 0):

Como te dicen, estás confundiendo los conceptos. En una aplicación web "común" (cliente/servidor) el servidor devuelve la página entera con todos los datos a mostrar, por lo que puede resultar confuso al pensar en móvil o SPA.

En una aplicación móvil o SPA se separan el backend y frontend para trabajar por separado y comunicarse a través de un api, es éste el que se aloja en un servidor y solo sirve la info que será mostrada en la aplicación móvil (o SPA), ya no sirve la página completa, ésta ya está en el cliente a la espera de la información que mostrará.

Para aclarar un poco sobre React Native, este framework no es sólo "híbrido", genera una aplicación nativa en la que incluso puedes usar Java, Objective-C o Swift en caso necesites algo muy específico que el framework no aporte, algo poco frecuente pero posible.

Comment: muchas gracias por la info y la orientación me ayudaste a entender más del tema,al parecer para lo que quiero hacer necesito de servicios web